# How to round WooCommerce product prices to the tens digit place?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, rounding, price

I've searched all over the net but couldn't find any solution to this. So I'm using a plugin to convert a fixed USD product price to AUD with the current USD/AUD exchange rate. It's running in real-time so the result would be like AUD $3257.2485131867.

Now I use the code snippet below to remove all the decimals so the price can be shown as $3257.00, which is great.

```
add_filter( 'raw_woocommerce_price', 'round_price_product', 10, 1);
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_excluding_tax', 'round_price_product', 10, 1 );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_including_tax', 'round_price_product', 10, 1 );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_tax_round', 'round_price_product', 10, 1);
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price', 'round_price_product', 10, 1);
add_filter( 'raw_woocommerce_price', 'round_price_product', 10, 1);
        
    // Return rounded price
    return round( $price );
}
```

But since the number $3257.00 doesn't look very pleasing, is there any way to round it up to $3260.00 so it looks better? Basically I want to show the digit in ones place as 0.

Similar wanted examples:

$2398 -> $2400

$5243 -> $5240

$7567 -> $7570

Any idea? Any input is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Note that the hook `woocommerce_get_price` is deprecated since WooCommerce 3 *( Also the function is missing in your code)*.

To round the product price to the tens, there is a 2nd argument in [`round()` PHP function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.round.php) that you can set to `-1` like:

```
round( $price, -1 )
```

Now here in your code with the replacement hooks for `woocommerce_get_price`:

```
add_filter( 'raw_woocommerce_price', 'round_price_product', 1000, 1 );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_get_price', 'round_price_product', 1000, 1 );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_get_regular_price', 'round_price_product', 1000, 1 );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_variation_get_price', 'round_price_product', 1000, 1 );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_variation_get_regular_price', 'round_price_product', 1000, 1 );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_excluding_tax', 'round_price_product', 1000, 1 );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_including_tax', 'round_price_product', 1000, 1 );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_tax_round', 'round_price_product', 1000, 1 );
function round_price_product( $price ){
    // Return rounded price
    return round( $price, -1 );
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). It should work.

Comment: Thanks so much LoicTheAztec, your code works like a charm and my site now looks so much better! Really appreciate it.